# How can i go to my website without typing "https://" in url. My website is hosted on aws cloudfront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have my website like this "https://hr.mywebsite.com", I am able to go to my website when i type the whole url(https://hr.mywebsite.com).

But I want to go to my website without typing "https://".

That is if i type "hr.mywebsite.com" it should open my website. My website is hosted on AWS CloudFront.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set an HTTP to HTTPS redirect on your CloudFront distribution. CloudFront has a setting for this.

**To configure CloudFront to require HTTPS between viewers and CloudFront**

Sign in to the AWS Management Console and open the CloudFront console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/.

In the top pane of the CloudFront console, choose the ID for the distribution that you want to update.

On the Behaviors tab, choose the cache behavior that you want to update, and then choose Edit.

Specify one of the following values for Viewer Protocol Policy:

Redirect HTTP to HTTPS
Viewers can use both protocols. HTTP GET and HEAD requests are automatically redirected to HTTPS requests. CloudFront returns HTTP status code 301 (Moved Permanently) along with the new HTTPS URL. The viewer then resubmits the request to CloudFront using the HTTPS URL.

Important
CloudFront doesn't redirect DELETE, OPTIONS, PATCH, POST, or PUT requests from HTTP to HTTPS. If you configure a cache behavior to redirect to HTTPS, CloudFront responds to HTTP DELETE, OPTIONS, PATCH, POST, or PUT requests for that cache behavior with HTTP status code 403 (Forbidden).
When a viewer makes an HTTP request that is redirected to an HTTPS request, CloudFront charges for both requests. For the HTTP request, the charge is only for the request and for the headers that CloudFront returns to the viewer. For the HTTPS request, the charge is for the request, and for the headers and the object that are returned by your origin.

From http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/using-https-viewers-to-cloudfront.html